# How to display Four labels content in a single label using sencha touch2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i am using sencha touch2. i want to display four label contents in a single label as shown below code. As per requirement i have only one label, for this label i need to add four labels contents. so in this contents i am using  tag to split each label. after generated apk/ipa file. in ipad its coming fine, it is displaying one after the another label as per our requirement. but in android phone it is not splitting the contents, the text is coming continuous without breaking the line. can someone tell how can i fix this issue. Thank you

```
Ext.define("MyPath", {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'SpecificationView',
    requires: ['Ext.Label'],
    config: {

        title: 'Specification',
        iconCls: 'star',
        scrollable: true,
        xtype: 'dataview',
        layout: {
            align: 'center',
            pack: 'center'
        },
        items: [                         
            {
                margin: '10',
                xtype: 'label',
                html: '<label><b>Flooring</b></label></br><label>Combination of Granite/Vitrified tiles in common areas. Vitrified tiles in foyer, living, dining and kitchen. Ceramic tiles in bedroom, balcony and utility.</label></br></br><label ><b>Doors & Windows</b></label></br><label>Apartment main door in teakwood frame with polished designer shutters. with mosquito mesh and safety grill</label>'
            }
            ]
    }
```

});

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your ipad output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @user1177921 try this please,

```
html: '<label><b>Flooring</b></label><br />' + 
      '<label>Combination of Granite/Vitrified tiles in common areas. Vitrified tiles in foyer, living, dining and kitchen. Ceramic tiles in bedroom, balcony and utility.</label><br />' + 
      '<label ><b>Doors & Windows</b></label><br />' + 
      '<label>Apartment main door in teakwood frame with polished designer shutters. with mosquito mesh and safety grill</label>'
```

I hope help you.